# Removing Stop words without tokenizing in Python

Tags: python, stop-words

I am trying to remove stop words from a list of strings from the exercise: [ipython file](https://colab.research.google.com/github/lmoroney/dlaicourse/blob/master/TensorFlow%20In%20Practice/Course%203%20-%20NLP/Course%203%20-%20Week%201%20-%20Exercise-answer.ipynb), my solution is as follows:

```
sentences = []
labels = []
with open("./bbc-text.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter =',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader: 
        labels.append(row[0])
        # clean up the sentence
        sentence = row[1]
        for word in stopwords: 
            if word in sentence: 
                sentence = sentence.replace(" "+ word + " ", "")
        sentences.append(sentence)

print(len(sentences))
```

But when I tokenize the words, the word index is 131530 which is much larger that it is expected:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(oov_token="<OOV>")
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sentences)
word_index = tokenizer.word_index
print(len(word_index))
# Expected output
# 29714
```

Here is the solution provided by the instructor:

```
sentences = []
labels = []
with open("./bbc-text.csv", 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        labels.append(row[0])
        sentence = row[1]
        for word in stopwords:
            token = " " + word + " "
            sentence = sentence.replace(token, " ")
            sentence = sentence.replace("  ", " ")
        sentences.append(sentence)
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Thank you,
CS

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your solution to the instructor's, you have:

```
sentence = sentence.replace(" "+ word + " ", "")
```

This replaces `" to "` with the empty string, converting the phrase "go to the store" to "gothe store". I suspect that you are "creating" quite a few non-existent words in this way, and this is causing the discrepancy. The instructor's solution replaces a stopword with a space, preventing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Because you concatenate two word in sentences after finding a stop word and it cause you loss other meaning words in next iteration. consider this example:
    "you are as i am"
all of the words in the sentence are stop words. Suppose stop word list as ["are","as","i","am","you"]
iteration 1: remove "are"
    youas i am
iteration 2: remove "as": **can not find it to remove!**
   youas i am
iteration 3:remove "i"
    youasam
as you see other words are modified.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I guess the solution is just adding space for the replacement string as follows.

```
if word in sentence: 
                sentence = sentence.replace(" "+ word + " ", " ")
```

Now, I see that if the stop word is that beginning or very end of each sentence, I need to add two more lines as follows:

```
 for word in stopwords:
        if word in sentence: 
            sentence = sentence.replace(" "+ word + " ", " ")
            sentence = sentence.replace(" "+ word , " ")
            sentence = sentence.replace(word + " ", " ")
    sentences.append(sentence)
```

Now I get even a shorter word_index.

CS